# How to use namespaces and folder structure correctly in Zend Framework models?

Tags: zend-framework, model, namespaces, naming-conventions

I've read about folder structure in Zend Framework and I wanted to put my application logic into correct place folder called `models`.
I've also read that Zend by default uses `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource`.

I've created subfolder `My/Service` and put there my php files.

Now I have copule of questions:

- Should classes in those files should be namespaced?

File is put in *application/models/My/Service/Page.php*

```
namespace My\Service;

class Page extends Service {
```

- How should I access this class in code?

  new Jubiler\Service\Page()
- How prefixes and namespaces are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are manyways for this..if you follow the exact naming concentions in zend framework..the class will load automatically ..heres the way\
1.In your config file add 
appnamespace = "Foo"
If you have a File called Test.php in your library folder with a folder Bar (/libray/Bar/Test.php then the class name must be Foo_Bar_Test 
In this way you can autoload the class